# Is there any way to refresh the page only for specific times in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, page-refresh

I am using jquery to reload a page with the below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
       setInterval(function() {
              window.location.reload();
                }, 10000); 
  })
</script>
```

But i had some requirement, that i need to refresh the page only for 6 times, and display a message that "Something problem occurred"

So how to refresh/reload a page only for specific times(6 in my case) using jquery ?

Comment: my question was how to reload the page only for 6 times, if i put semicolon at the end of document ready function, it will reload only for 6 times ?

Comment: You're going to have to use query strings or cookies for this. Without them, JavaScript won't care what it's done before a new page load.

Comment: Use a cookie or Storage and then check against it on every refresh and clear the interval accordingly.

Comment: @LShetty: Can you provide an example, because that will be helpful not only for me but for every one who sees this post

Comment: Storage in HTML5: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp and Cookies: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment of LShetty:

A basic example of using **localStorage** could be seen here http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

E.g. something along the lines

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
       var counter = localStorage.getItem('counter');
       if (counter == null) {
         counter = 0;
       }
       counter++;
       if (counter<=6) {
         localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
         setInterval( function() {
                         window.location.reload();
                      }, 10000 );
       }
  })
</script>
```

Of course you could use a **cookie** for the same purpose, as you are going to store just a counter (way bellow the 4K limit of data stored in a cookie). For example you could utilize the createCookie and readCookie functions from the following article http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea: you can use query string to pass the counter between page refreshes. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var counter = 0;
  $(document).ready(function(){
       counter = parseInt(getParameterByName("counter"));
       if(counter < 6){
       setInterval(function() {
              window.location.href = "http://" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?counter=' + (counter + 1);
                }, 10000); 
       }
  })

//convenient method to get parameters from query string 
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Anyone can update anything on the client. What's your point? One can also just close the browser.

Comment: My point is store the counter on either at server side or browser's cookie etc.

Comment: I just don't think that the OP's process is that critical to store it on the server. I agree, using cookies may be less ugly.

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
$(function(){
 if($('#sessioncounter').val() <= 6 ){
   setTimeout(function(){
    window.location = window.location;
   }, 6000);
 }
});
```

`$('#sessioncounter').val()` gives the counter value which you save in every load in the session. i dont know what kind of backend language you are using.. anyway, make a hidden field

```
<input type='hidden' id='sessioncounter' />
```

then save after each reload the counter into this field.

Comment: I am using django/python

Answer (score 0):

Using hash variables also works when it's an older browser without localstorage.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var count = parseInt(window.location.hash.replace('#',''))
        if(!count){
            count = 0;
        }
        count++;
        if(count < 7){
        setTimeout(function(){ window.location = 'http://'+window.location.hostname+window.location.pathname+'#'+count;}, 1000); 
        }
});
```